# Why should I bind the index buffer to draw elements with a VAO?

Tags: opengl, vertex-array-object, index-buffer

I use the following code to render a simple quad using a vertex array and an index buffer.

In the [Vertex specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers), I see

> The index buffer binding is stored within the VAO.

But in my code, in the render loop, I need to bind the index buffer to see the quad.

---

The data:

```cpp
float mesh[24] = {
        // pos           // color
          0, 0,  0,      1, 1, 0,
        -.5, 0,  0,      0, 1, 1,
        -.5, 0, .5,      1, 0, 1,
          0, 0, .5,      1, 1, 1
};
int indices[6] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
```

The initialization of the buffers:

```cpp
GLuint vao{};
GLuint buffers[2]{};

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(float), mesh, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

And in the main loop, I use:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]); // Why this line is necessary ?
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Why should I use `glBindBuffer()` with `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` in the render loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this line is necessary ?

It is not necessary. However, the element buffer reference is stored in the VAO. Just remove `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`. This line breaks the binding of the index buffer and to the VAO.

The [Index Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) binding is stored within the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). When `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO)` is called the element buffer object ID is stored in the currently bound Vertex Array Object. Therefore the VAO must be bound before the element buffer with `glBindVertexArray(VAO)`.

Unlike to the [Index Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers), the [Vertex Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) binding (`ARRAY_BUFFER`) is a global state.
Each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different `ARRAY_BUFFER`. When [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is associated to the specified attribute index and the ID of the object is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO.